# Make matched letters highlighted in autocomplete in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I have a set of airport names along with their codes to be displayed in autocomplete.

E.g. Amsterdem (AMS)

I want to match the value entered in the search box,I want to display the matched airport name as well as airportcode bold as follows.

if I enter **ams** in search box,i want to highlight '**Ams**'terdem ('**AMS**') in my autocomplete.

I have written a code as below:

```
function () {
    var oldFn = $.ui.autocomplete.prototype._renderItem;
    $.ui.autocomplete.prototype._renderItem = function( ul, item) {
        var re = new RegExp("^" + this.term, "i") ;
        var t = item.label.replace(re,"<span style='font-weight:bold;'>" + this.term + "</span>");
        return $( "<li></li>" )
            .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
            .append( "<a>" + t + "</a>" )
            .appendTo( ul );
    };
};
```

it results as '**Ams**'terdem (AMS) instead of '**Ams**'terdem (**AMS**).

Note:Amsterdem (AMS) is a single term

Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to change

```
var re = new RegExp("^" + this.term, "i") ;
```

with this code

```
var re = new RegExp(this.term, "ig") ;
```

this will replace all instance in your string

"^" denotes start of string, and "g" in regular expression works on all instance

[here](http://jsbin.com/juveqotu/1/) is working example

replace your code with this one

```
function () {
var oldFn = $.ui.autocomplete.prototype._renderItem;
$.ui.autocomplete.prototype._renderItem = function( ul, item) {
    var re = new RegExp(this.term, "ig") ;
    var t = item.label.replace(re,"<span style='font-weight:bold;'>" + this.term + "</span>");
    return $( "<li></li>" )
        .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
        .append( "<a>" + t + "</a>" )
        .appendTo( ul );
};
};
```

Comment: this is working fine this this example http://jsbin.com/bonatine/1/edit and please share your code in jsbin

Comment: Thanks.I tried.But only airport name gets highlighted but the airport code

Comment: share your code using www.jsbin.com, hope i will help you

Comment: Sorry I cannot access JSbin.Above is my code.just I replaced as u have instructed

Comment: as per my answer i have created a demo which is working as per your requirement.

Comment: The input entered in the search autocomplete is (e.g)Amst.. and the requirement is 'Amst'erdem('AMS')(the letters within the quotes should be made as bold)

Comment: my code is working as per your requirement i think you haven't tested my demo http://jsbin.com/juveqotu/1 start typying ams...

Comment: Great.it works.Thanks.now for London Hethrew Airport(LHR),if i enter 'lhr',there is no matched items getting displayed.can you help me on this please?

Comment: Note; `RegExp(this.term, "ig")` will cause drama (may even throw a JavaScript error) if the search term is anything that could be parsed as regex, particularly things like brackets or the dollar sign.