# Jquery autocomplete highlight text

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I want to make matched text in string bold in autocomplete I got great help from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435964/jqueryui-how-can-i-custom-format-the-autocomplete-plug-in-results).

This doesnt it for single word or word which are in sequence I want to make words bold no matter in which order they are.

I want to make each and every word matching in the string bold

```
var t = "Cadbury Gems 100gm Tasty";
var wordArr = 'gems tasty'.toLowerCase().replace(/\b[a-z]/g, function (letter) {
    return letter.toUpperCase();
}).split(' ');
$.each(wordArr, function (i) {
    console.log(wordArr[i]);
    var re = new RegExp("^" + wordArr[i], "i");
    t = t.replace(re, "<span style='font-weight:bold;color:Blue;'>" + wordArr[i] + "</span>");

})
console.log(t);
var li = $("<li></li>")
//.data("item.autocomplete", item)
.append("<a style='text-align:left'>" + t + "</a>")
    .appendTo($('#ul'));
```

MY [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2bFL2/)

I tried with `$.each` But doesnt work. Any ideas.

Comment: I tried this solution, worked for me:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/23865580/4533433

Answer (score 0):

Try this one build with jQuery UI widget factory:

```
$.widget("custom.autocompleteHighlight", $.ui.autocomplete, {
            _renderItem: function (ul, item) {
                var regexp = new RegExp('(' + this.term + ')', 'gi'),
                    classString = this.options.highlightClass ?  ' class="' + this.options.highlightClass + '"' : '',
                    label = item.label.replace(regexp, '<span' + classString + '>$1</span>');

                return $('<li><a href="#">' + label + '</a></li>').appendTo(ul);
            }
    }
});
```

You now can use it with:

```
$('input.jsAutocompleteHighlight').autocompleteHighlight({
        highlightClass: 'ui-autocomplete-hightlight'
});
```

CSS styling:

```
.ui-autocomplete-highlight {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
mynew = item.label
$.each(this.term.split(' '),function(k,v){
    var re = new RegExp(v,'i')
    mynew = mynew.replace(re,'<span style="color:red">' + v + '</span>');
})
```